# Why does Microsoft.Build.Exceution.BuildManager fail build when a project has Enable Code Analysis On Build turned on?

Tags: c#, build, code-analysis

I am working on an application that writes test code based on scenarios from a user. However, one of the supporting test framework projects, I want to turn on `Enable Code Analysis on Build`. The Test project the app writes to references that test framework project.

```
var globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
     {"OutputPath", "bin\\Debug"},
     {"Configuration","Debug"}
};
var pc = new ProjectCollection();
var consoleLogger = new ConsoleLogger();
pc.RegisterLogger(consoleLogger);
var bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(PATHTOSOLUTION, globalProperty, "4.0", new[] { "Build" }, null);
var buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, buildRequest);
if (buildResult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success)
{
     return true;
}
return false;
```

if through `Visual Studio` if I open the solution and manually trigger `Build` as `Run Code Analysis on Solution`, it reports no issues.

With the code above it reports an overall `Failure` with `Code Analysis` on but `Success` with it turned off.